# How to convert Id to String in Apex?

Tags: apex, typecast

I've been searching the documentation for this, without much luck so far. In particular I'd like to convert an Id to a 18-char string, and ideally read about that in documentation to verify its the recommended approach.

I've seen various approaches including

```
String str = '' + someId;
```

Is this the same as

```
String str = (String)someId;
```

I've also seen

```
String str = String.valueOf(someId);
```

However when I tried that I got 15-char strings! Why is that?!

What is the recommended approach to always guarantee an 18-char string from an Id?

Answer (score 16):

You need to get it as `Id.valueOf('someId')`. This will return the 18 char id. See below:

```
String strId = Id.valueOf('yourId');
```

This will store the 18 char Id in String format.

Comment: I don't want an Id result, I want an 18-char string as the result

Comment: It will work with strings.. updated the answer.